# How to update an incorrect normalized location from Here API

Tags: geolocation, here-api

We use Here API to get normalized locations from certain geocodings. For the geocoding of "DEU, RP, Frankenthal (Pfalz)", Here returns the normalized location as "Wissen, Rhineland-Palatinate, DEU". Is there a way to get the normalized location to be returned as Frankenthal instead of Wissen for that geocoding?

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for Fankenthal as City and not as district? 
This is an interesting example as Frankenthal ios available as a district, as a city as well as a street name.
The structured search might be a better option for your use case:

https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?&&city=Frankenthal&country=DEU&gen=9&app_id=yyy&app_code=xxx

```
 "Address": {
                "Label": "Frankenthal (Pfalz), Rheinland-Pfalz, Deutschland",
                "Country": "DEU",
                "State": "Rheinland-Pfalz",
                "County": "Frankenthal (Pfalz)",
                "City": "Frankenthal (Pfalz)",
                "PostalCode": "67227",
```